# time zone offset is incorrect in node after that in our location we don't have DST anymore

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, dst, timezone-offset

time zone offset must be -210 but node shows -270, so as a result I get a wrong `date.toLocaleString()`. although it's correct in browsers' terminal

```
const d = new Date() // => 2023-06-18T07:51:26.742Z
d.toLocaleString() // => '6/18/2023, 12:21:26 PM' // time should be: 11:21:26
d.getTimezoneOffset() // => -270 //should be -210
```

I also tried setting locale and options in `toLocaleString` , but no progress!
One thing I should mention is that we had +1:00 hr. DST before, but now the governments decided not to have an associated daylight saving time. Is it possible that maybe and update on node is needed? if not how should I fix this?

the time in my pc is correct

node version: 16.16.0

Comment: It would be useful if you gave us the actual name of the timezone. Here is a github issue https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3866

Comment: It is +3:30 Asia/Tehran @mplungjan

Comment: Likely you're correct and that version of Node's timezone database has not been updated. Tehran has decided not to use DST from 2023 to 2029 (and lots of other places are thinking of ditching it too). Please edit the OP to add the timezone.